# Can gl_WorkGroupSize be set outside the compute shader?

Tags: opengl, compute-shader, cuda

I am migrating code from CUDA to OpenGL compute shaders.
I could not find a way to set the local workgroup size outside the shader; is there a way to set gl_WorkGroupSize in the calling program like one can do for gl_NumWorkGroups?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Core OpenGL has no mechanism for this. The [ARB_compute_variable_group_size](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_compute_variable_group_size.txt) extension provides such a feature. It doesn't allow for indirect compute operations though.

It [doesn't seem to have much AMD support](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/listreports.php?extension=GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size) though (outside of open source Linux drivers). And Intel support is nil.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the more direct existing answer, there *is* a way to work around this in unextended OpenGL to some degree, feeding from the fact that in contrast to CUDA OpenGL compute shaders are *not* pre-compiled with application build (well, they *can* nowadays, but aren't by default). Instead you *usually* compile your compute shaders at some point during application runtime.

So a way to achieve a somewhat customizable workgroup size is to use a **macro for it and then redefine this dynamically during application runtime but *before* shader compile time**.

```
layout(local_size_x = BLOCKSIZE) in;
```

And in the application all you have to do is prepend a `"#define BLOCKSIZE <whatever>\n"` to the shader source string you feed into `glCompileShader`. Of course in practice you have to care about stuff like the `#version` directive being the first line in a shader. You could as well have the define in the shader code already (maybe with a meaningful default size) and do a text replacement instead. But you get the idea.

Of course this means **recompiling your compute shader for each and every workgroup size** you're using. It's practically not much different from just having different shaders for each workgroup size. But at least it's a way to dynamically select the workgroup size during runtime while maintaining a single shader source.